# bootstrap3-datetimepicker doesn't always work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker

I am using [meteor-bootstrap3-datetimepicker](https://github.com/tsega/meteor-bootstrap3-datetimepicker).

Below is where I am using the date picker:

```html
<form id="addAppointment" style="display:none">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-lg-8 col-md-8">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="dateTimeTextField"
               type="text"
               class="form-control datetimepicker"
               data-DateTimePicker
               name="appointment"
               placeholder="Pick a Date">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <a id="adjustDateTime"
           class="btn btn-success btn-outline btn-block">Adjust Date and Time</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I used `onRendered` as it was shown in their GitHub page:

```js
Template.requestView.onRendered(function() {
    this.$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
});
```

What I expect: datetime popup opened when I press on the textfield (`<input>` tag), as it shown in pictures below:

[image]

[image]

The problem is that the datetime popup only appeared to me three times: once in Google Chrome and twice in Safari.

Why does it rarely appear when I press on the textfield?

Comment: What is that `data-DateTimePicker` attribute in `<input>` tag?

Comment: I got it from the following tutorial https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/adding-a-date-and-time-picker

Comment: @Styx " in order to access the library's methods for getting our date from the input, the library requires us to use the data-DateTimePicker attribute on our input."