# How can I load jQuery first in my application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I am using [meteor-bootstrap3-datetimepicker](https://github.com/tsega/meteor-bootstrap3-datetimepicker) package and when I try to run my application, I stumble across the following error:

> bootstrap-datetimepicker requires jQuery to be loaded first

How can I make sure that jQuery is loaded first?

**NOTE:** I am not adding the package with `meteor add tsega:bootstrap3-datetimepicker`. Instead, I am following [this](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/adding-a-date-and-time-picker) tutorial in which I download the `js` and `css` file manually and added them to the project.

**NOTE 2:** I tried to download the package with `meteor add tsega:bootstrap3-datetimepicker` but it didn't work for me and I posted a question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46505578/bootstrap3-datetimepicker-doesnt-always-work-as-expected?noredirect=1#comment79975474_46505578).

I guess adding the package didn't work it up because `jQuery` is not loaded first.

How can I make sure `jQuery` loads first in my project?

Comment: Are you using npm to pull in your files?

Comment: @RajendranNadar I am downloading the package from their links through (File -> Save As ..)

Comment: Did you place these 2 files into `client/lib/`?

Comment: @Styx it was my mistake, it moved it there, now it doesn't show me the error "bootstrap-datetimepicker requires jQuery to be loaded first". but it doesn't work, the Calendar doesn't appear when I click on the input field

Comment: @BehrouzRiahi Perhaps, you should remove this question and ask a new one?